# Jython-standalone 2.7.2:- ImportError: No module named os in <script> at line number 1

Tags: java, python, jython, jython-2.7

I am trying to take a python  script as an input from the user and execute it. I am using maven as project manager.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.python</groupId>
            <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Following is the structure of the jython package: [image: Jython package structure]

I have moved from jython to jython-standalone package, as suggested in multiple answers for the similar questions. Even while trying to run a simple python script I keep on getting the error:

```
import os
import uuid
import sys
# from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import subprocess

def process(item, interceptor):
    logger.info("Starting subprocess...")
```

```
javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named os in <script> at line number 1
    at
```

I am unable to understand the issue and how can it be resolved.

Comment: Exactly how do you run the script?

Comment: I am running on ogsi runtime env using apache karaf

Comment: How can we reproduce the problem? See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to create an OSGi bundle that wraps the jython standalone jar? (example: https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.x/developers-guide/creating-bundles.html)